# Shouldn't My Google Account have the Same Reputation on all StackExchange Sites?

Tags: support, user-accounts

When i Logged in into [Meta Stack Exchange](http://Meta.Stackexchange.com) i used my Google Account and it told me to Create it to all Stack Exchange Sites and i Accepted

Now when i opened Ask Ubuntu i had the Same Log in message

Same for Stack Over Flow, is this normal? also my Reputations are not Shared Across the accounts and it looks like this is the first time i login.

Comment: Your reputation will not be shared across accounts, no.  Each site has it's own norms and quirks; what you know in one area does not transfer over to another, so neither does your reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they aren't - and why would they? Why should a programmer with a high rep on Stack Overflow be able to carry that over to an SE where they know nothing of the subject?

Comment: "Why should a programmer with a high rep on Stack Overflow be able to carry that over to an SE where they know nothing of the subject?" - That is a separate question.

Comment: Uh, it wasn't an actual question - it was to point out to the OP how silly that idea would be.